# jQuery .load is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 3.2.1 and this code

```
// /js/main.js

$(function () {

  var targetId = 'about';

  var container = $('#pages').find('.active').removeClass('active').end()
                             .find('#' + targetId).addClass('active');

  console.log(container, container.load);

  if (!container.data('loaded')) {
    container.load('/pages/' + targetId + '.html');
  }

});
```

produce this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: container.load is not a function
```

The output for `container` and `container.load` is

```
[div#about.tab-pane.active, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)] undefined
```

I don't understand why I get this error.

---

### Edit

I have no idea why people want the HTML, but here is the relevant part of it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div id="pages" class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane default" id="about"></div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see what console.log(container) returns , seems there is no elemnt with `'#' + targetId`

Comment: @bRIMOs That shouldn't make a difference. It should just be an empty collection, but still have all the jQuery methods.

Comment: @Barmar yep agree .

Comment: Strange that it doesn't get an error on `container.data()`. If it's not a jQuery object it shouldn't have either method.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: I also encountered some error similar to this before. It turned out my import of jQuery file is in a later order of my script, so when executing my script, jQuery has not yet been imported.

Comment: @MichaelTong except this is not the case, here. 1) I import jQuery in the BODY section, and my custom script after. 2) the code I pasted above is inside `$(function () { ... code pasted here ... });`.

Comment: @styfle I'm not sure what posting the relevant HTML would produce. As others mentioned, executing `$('#whatever').load(...)` should work regardless if the selector returns anything or not.

Comment: Question edited. I hope this helps.

Comment: @YanickRochon Can you also post html code?

Comment: There's no AJAX in jQuery slim. Use the full version. Voting to close

Comment: Try to use this on your HTML: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">